# Colocar dos divs horizontalmente ocupando todo el ancho de la página

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de colocar dos cajas que una junto a la otra que ocupen todo el ancho de la página, por ejemplo mitad y mitad, no puedo poner en 50% porque aparece una pequeña separación entre ambas que lo impide, pongo una con un ancho del 49% para que se aprecie. ¿Porque me aparece este espacio?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra cosa que ocurre, es que según la resolución y el texto contenido una de las cajas salta hacia abajo dejando un espacio vació arriba. Tiene que ver con el texto contenido porque si se intercambian los textos, tambien lo hacen las cajas que saltan abajo. ¿Puedo arreglar estos problemas sin floats, flexbox, etc?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```css
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        p {
            margin: 1em;
        }

        .cols {
            height: 300px;
        }
            .col1 {
                background-color: orange;
                width: 50%;
            }
            .col2 {
                background-color: skyblue;
                width: 49%;
            }
            .col1,
            .col2 {
                display: inline-block;
                height: 100%;
            }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="cols">
        <div class="col1">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa eveniet, omnis ut, qui aspernatur neque unde velit officia molestias nostrum necessitatibus itaque placeat incidunt ratione. Earum sequi, odio quia illum?
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, omnis atque tempore aliquid ab laboriosam sapiente, vitae natus excepturi dolor eveniet earum veritatis temporibus. Repellat voluptatibus quam, tenetur rem aut.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes hacerlo de muchas formas, [como muestra este artículo de CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/left-and-right/).

Aquí te dejo solamente dos:

### Con FlexBox:

```css
.cols {
  display: flex;
}

.cols div {
  flex: 1;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

p {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
  <div class="col1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa eveniet, omnis ut, qui aspernatur neque unde velit officia molestias nostrum necessitatibus itaque placeat incidunt ratione. Earum sequi, odio quia illum?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, omnis atque tempore aliquid ab laboriosam sapiente, vitae natus excepturi dolor eveniet earum veritatis temporibus. Repellat voluptatibus quam, tenetur rem aut.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, omnis atque tempore aliquid ab laboriosam sapiente, vitae natus excepturi dolor eveniet earum veritatis temporibus. Repellat voluptatibus quam, tenetur rem aut.
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Con Table:

```css
.cols {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.cols div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

p {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
  <div class="col1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa eveniet, omnis ut, qui aspernatur neque unde velit officia molestias nostrum necessitatibus itaque placeat incidunt ratione. Earum sequi, odio quia illum?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, omnis atque tempore aliquid ab laboriosam sapiente, vitae natus excepturi dolor eveniet earum veritatis temporibus. Repellat voluptatibus quam, tenetur rem aut.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, omnis atque tempore aliquid ab laboriosam sapiente, vitae natus excepturi dolor eveniet earum veritatis temporibus. Repellat voluptatibus quam, tenetur rem aut.
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¡Larga vida a Flexbox y buena respuesta! (en unos minutos borraré este comentario)